# Error while installing Spring Tool 3 plugin in Eclipse : "requires 'java.package; javax.servlet ' but it could not be found" Need help fixing this

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, eclipse-plugin, sts

I am not able to install STS 3 to eclipse.

Using : java-19 version &
Eclipse Enterprise  Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)

Error Message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Web Flow Extension (optional) 3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.feature.feature.group 3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring Web 4.3.23.20190313-CI (org.springframework.web 4.3.23.20190313-CI) requires 'java.package; javax.servlet [2.4.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Web Flow Extension (optional) 3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.feature.feature.group 3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.web [4.3.23.20190313-CI,4.3.23.20190313-CI]
```

[image: SS of installation error message]

Tried to install STS 3 Plugin

Comment: The plugin/bundle `javax.servlet` is missing. Does in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03) help (more recent releases do not contain `javax.servlet` anymore). [STS 3 is end of life](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-3-add-spring-tools-4) and might not work in recent version of Eclipse. Better use [Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tool Suite 4)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4).